# hide back menu button if page was opened as a blank

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to hide a back button (in nav menu) if current page was opened with target="_blank".

in usual case this page is called as:

```
<a href="/about_us/" class="nav-li" >About Us</a>
```

in another case it is called with:

```
<a href="/about_us/" class="nav-li" target="_blank" >About Us</a>
```

The code at the target page for the back button is:

```
<label class="nav-li" for="back">Back</label>
<input class='Back' id = "back" type=button value="Back" onClick="history.go(-1)">
```

How to hide this button if opened as blank ???

Whole project is on Django

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just hide the `button` if the `history` object has a `length` <del>of null</del> less than 2 . This could be done with a css-class, pure css or direct with JS

[EDIT]:

I would add this to the `onload` event of the new form.

```
function init(){
  if(history.length < 2){
    document.getElementById('Back').style.display = none;
  }
}

[...]

<body onload="init()">

[...]
```

Comment: I believe `history.length` would be `1` if the history is "fresh" rather than `null`.

Comment: good point! But I'm not sure if it have to be 0 or 1  ... you have to try it :)

Comment: According to the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History) it's supposed to be `1` for a fresh history.

Comment: I've change my solution. :P

Answer (score 0):

You should heck the history object if the length is less or equal to 1 so it haven't a history, so you can hide your btn

```
window.onload = function (){
     var hasHistory = history.length <= 1; //if has an history;
     document.getElementById('cacca').style.display = hasHistory ? "none" : "block";

}
```